# Uncaught ReferenceError: showMenu is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, uncaught-reference-error

I am working on a Notes Website and I seem to be having issues with my JavaScript function. I call it in my php code and it keeps talking about an Uncaught Reference Error and I have been unable to find a solution.

These are my codes below.

notes.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Fetch notes for the current user
$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user_id = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Notes | Noted App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="notes.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Iconscout Link For Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="center"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="upward"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="forward"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="popup-box">
      <div class="popup">
        <div class="content">
          <header>
            <p></p>
            <i class="uil uil-times"></i>
          </header>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="row title">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" spellcheck="false" id="title">
            </div>
            <div class="row description">
              <label for="desc">Description</label>
              <textarea spellcheck="false" id="desc"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <li class="add-box">
        <div class="icon"><i class="uil uil-plus"></i></div>
        <p>Add new note</p>
      </li>
      <div class="notes-list">'; // Start the notes list
      
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Format the date
        $formattedDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['date_published']));
    
        echo '<li class="note">
                <div class="details">
                    <p>' . $row['title'] . '</p>
                    <span>' . nl2br($row['description']) . '</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-content"> 
                    <span>' . $formattedDate . '</span>
                    <div class="settings">
                        <i onclick="showMenu(this)" class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li onclick="updateNote(' . $row['id'] . ', \'' . $row['title'] . '\', \'' . addslashes($row['description']) . '\')"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>Edit</li>
                            <li onclick="deleteNote(' . $row['id'] . ')"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>Delete</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>';
    }

        echo '</div></div><script src="script.js"></script></body></html>';
    } else {
        echo "Error fetching notes.";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    const addBox = document.querySelector(".add-box");
    const popupBox = document.querySelector(".popup-box");
    const popupTitle = popupBox.querySelector("header p");
    const closeIcon = popupBox.querySelector("header i");
    const titleTag = popupBox.querySelector("input");
    const descTag = popupBox.querySelector("textarea");
    const addBtn = popupBox.querySelector("button");
  
    const notesList = document.querySelector(".notes-list");

  
    addBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
      popupTitle.innerText = "Add a new Note";
      addBtn.innerText = "Add Note";
      popupBox.classList.add("show");
      document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "hidden";
      if (window.innerWidth > 660) titleTag.focus();
    });
  
    closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
      titleTag.value = descTag.value = "";
      popupBox.classList.remove("show");
      document.querySelector("body").style.overflow = "auto";
    });
  
    function showNotes() {
      // Send an AJAX request to fetch notes
      fetch("fetch_notes.php")
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data && data.length > 0) {
            notesList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing notes
            data.forEach((note) => {
              let filterDesc = note.description.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
              let liTag = `
                          <li class="note">
                              <div class="details">
                                  <h3>${note.title}</h3>
                                  <p>${filterDesc}</p>
                                  <p>Date Published: ${note.date}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="bottom-content">
                                  <div class="settings">
                                      <i onclick="showMenu(this)" class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
                                      <ul class="menu">
                                          <li onclick="updateNote(${note.id}, '${note.title}', '${filterDesc}')"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>Edit</li>
                                          <li onclick="deleteNote(${note.id})"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>Delete</li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                      `;
              notesList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", liTag);
            });
          } else {
            // Handle case where there are no notes or the data is empty
            notesList.innerHTML = "<p>No notes available.</p>";
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching notes:", error);
          // Handle other errors, e.g., network issues or server errors
          notesList.innerHTML = "<p>Error fetching notes. Please try again later.</p>";
        });
    }
  
    showNotes();

    // Initialize the openMenu variable
let openMenu = null;

// Define the showMenu function
function showMenu(triggeringElement, menu) {
  // If another menu is open, close it
  if (openMenu !== null && openMenu !== menu) {
    openMenu.classList.remove("show");
  }

  // Toggle the menu
  if (menu.classList.contains('show')) {
    menu.classList.remove('show');
    openMenu = null;
  } else {
    menu.classList.add('show');
    openMenu = menu;
  }

  // Close the menu when clicking outside of it
  document.addEventListener('click', function closeMenu(event) {
    if (!menu.contains(event.target)) {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
      document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      openMenu = null;
    }
  });
}

// Attach the showMenu function to your settings icons
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const notesList = document.getElementById("notesList");
  notesList.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    const settingsIcon = event.target.closest(".settings i");
    if (settingsIcon) {
      const menu = settingsIcon.nextElementSibling;
      showMenu(settingsIcon, menu);
    }
  });
});

  
    function deleteNote(noteId) {
      let confirmDel = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
      if (!confirmDel) return;
  
      // Send a DELETE request to delete the note
      fetch("delete_note.php", {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: noteId }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.success) {
            showNotes(); // Refresh the notes list
          } else {
            console.error("Error deleting note:", data.error);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error deleting note:", error);
        });
    }
  
    function updateNote(noteId, title, filterDesc) {
      let description = filterDesc.replaceAll("<br/>", "\r\n");
      addBox.click();
      titleTag.value = title;
      descTag.value = description;
      popupTitle.innerText = "Update a Note";
      addBtn.innerText = "Update Note";
  
      // Store the note ID to use when updating
      addBtn.dataset.noteId = noteId;
    }
  
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let title = titleTag.value.trim();
      let description = descTag.value.trim();
  
      if (title || description) {
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let month = months[currentDate.getMonth()]; // Change 'month' to 'months'
        let day = currentDate.getDate();
        let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
        let noteInfo = { title, description, date: `${month} ${day}, ${year}` };
  
        let isUpdate = !!addBtn.dataset.noteId;
        let url = isUpdate ? "update_note.php" : "add_note.php";
  
        if (isUpdate) {
          noteInfo.id = addBtn.dataset.noteId;
        }
  
        // Send an AJAX request to add/update the note
        fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(noteInfo),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            if (data.success) {
              showNotes(); // Refresh the notes list
              closeIcon.click(); // Close the popup
            } else {
              console.error("Error saving note:", data.error);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error saving note:", error);
          });
      }
    });
  });
```

Something is also intefering with the card display of my notes. The title, description and date are not being displayed the way they were styled in my css. I have added my css code just in case anyone can help with that.

notes.css

```
/* Import Google Font - Poppins */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #88ABFF;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #618cf8;
}
.wrapper{
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 265px);
}
.wrapper li{
  height: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
.add-box, .icon, .bottom-content, 
.popup, header, .settings .menu li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.add-box{
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.add-box .icon{
  height: 78px;
  width: 78px;
  color: #88ABFF;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px dashed #88ABFF;
}
.add-box p{
  color: #88ABFF;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.note{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.note .details{
  max-height: 165px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.note .details::-webkit-scrollbar,
.popup textarea::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 5px;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.note p{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.note span{
  display: block;
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.note .bottom-content{
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.bottom-content span{
  color: #6D6D6D;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.bottom-content .settings{
  position: relative;
}
.bottom-content .settings i{
  color: #6D6D6D;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.settings .menu{
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.settings.show .menu{
  transform: scale(1);
}
.settings .menu li{
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 17px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.menu li:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.menu li:hover{
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.menu li i{
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.popup-box{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.popup-box .popup{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.95);
}
.popup-box, .popup{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.popup-box.show, .popup-box.show .popup{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.popup-box.show .popup{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.popup .content{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.content header{
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content header p{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.content header i{
  color: #8b8989;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.content form{
  margin: 15px 25px 35px;
}
.content form .row{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form .row label{
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
form :where(input, textarea){
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
form :where(input, textarea):focus{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
}
form .row textarea{
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
form button{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #6A93F8;
}

@media (max-width: 660px){
  .wrapper{
    margin: 15px;
    gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100%);
  }
  .popup-box .popup{
    max-width: calc(100% - 15px);
  }
  .bottom-content .settings i{
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  .nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 12px;
  }
  .nav-links li a{
    position: relative;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-links li a:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    background: #34efdf;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .nav-links li a:hover:before{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-links li.center a:before{
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  .nav-links li.upward a:before{
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li.upward a:hover:before{
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-links li.forward a:before{
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  }
  .nav-links li.forward a:hover:before{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
  }

  .notes-list {
    display: contents;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
```

I keep getting the Uncaught Reference Error when i click on the settings icon which is supposed to display the edit and delete buttons.

I have tried everything, but that error won't go away.

Comment: how about making it to ```window.showMenu = function(){}``` ?

Comment: @cantdocpp the error has stopped showing, thank you! However, it now shows **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at showMenu (script.js:38:21)** which is in reference to this part of my script.js code `menuElement.style.top = `${menuTop}px`;`

Comment: I don't see any ```menuElement.style.top``` in your code

Comment: @cantdocpp my bad, I was mixing it up with something up. The error has gone! Nothing happens when I click on the settings icon though. Don't know if you can help with that or give some advice? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP? Please remove the irrelevant parts

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is to change how button click is handled.
Don't use it like this:

```
<i onclick="showMenu(this)" ...
```

Intead of this add some class and attach as `addEventListener("click"...`

```
<i class="showMenu" class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>

<script>
    showMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
        showMenu();
    });
</script>
```

And I saw that function `showMenu` accept as a first param `triggeringElement`, but that variable is never used.

**EXPLANATION:**

The `DOMContentLoaded` can be written different that you used, but with same results.

Function `showMenu` in this example is inside `ready` function that is called on page load. Because `showMenu` is not root function, it is nested inside other function, we can't call her directly without `window` prefix

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    ready();
});

function ready() {
    /* ... some code here */

    function showMenu() {
        console.log("showMenu function is called");
    }

    window.showMenu_2 = function () {
        console.log("window function showMenu_2 is called");
    };

    /* some code here ... */
}
```

Function `showMenu_2` can be used as you want in your code

**EXAMPLE**

Here is an example for adding a click event instead of onclick attribute

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Define variable
  const show_menu = document.querySelector(".showMenu");

  // Button click event
  show_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
      showMenu();
  });

  // Define the showMenu function
  function showMenu(triggeringElement, menu) {
      console.log("showMenu");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Import Google Font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #88abff;
}
::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #618cf8;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 265px);
}
.wrapper li {
  height: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.add-box,
.icon,
.bottom-content,
.popup,
header,
.settings .menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.add-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.add-box .icon {
  height: 78px;
  width: 78px;
  color: #88abff;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px dashed #88abff;
}
.add-box p {
  color: #88abff;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.note {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.note .details {
  max-height: 165px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.note .details::-webkit-scrollbar,
.popup textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.note .details:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.popup textarea:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.note p {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.note span {
  display: block;
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.note .bottom-content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.bottom-content span {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.bottom-content .settings {
  position: relative;
}
.bottom-content .settings i {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.settings .menu {
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.settings.show .menu {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.settings .menu li {
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 17px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.menu li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.menu li i {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.popup-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.popup-box .popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.95);
}
.popup-box,
.popup {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.popup-box.show,
.popup-box.show .popup {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.popup-box.show .popup {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.popup .content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.content header {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.content header i {
  color: #8b8989;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.content form {
  margin: 15px 25px 35px;
}
.content form .row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form .row label {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
form :where(input, textarea) {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
form :where(input, textarea):focus {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
form .row textarea {
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
form button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #6a93f8;
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: 15px;
    gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100%);
  }
  .popup-box .popup {
    max-width: calc(100% - 15px);
  }
  .bottom-content .settings i {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 12px;
}
.nav-links li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  background: #34efdf;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.nav-links li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-links li.center a:before {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.nav-links li.upward a:before {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-links li.upward a:hover:before {
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-links li.forward a:before {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.nav-links li.forward a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.notes-list {
  display: contents;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Notes | Noted App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- Iconscout Link For Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="popup-box">
            <div class="popup">
                <div class="content">
                    <header>
                        <p></p>
                        <i class="uil uil-times"></i>
                    </header>
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="row title">
                            <label for="title">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" spellcheck="false" id="title" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row description">
                            <label for="desc">Description</label>
                            <textarea spellcheck="false" id="desc"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="notes-list">
                <li class="note">
                    <div class="details">
                        <p>Some title</p>
                        <span>description</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-content">
                        <span>12.12.2012</span>
                        <div class="settings">
                            <i class="showMenu uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li onclick="updateNote(1)"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>Edit</li>
                                <li onclick="deleteNote(1)"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>Delete</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried it just as you suggested, but it still shows the same error when I click the settings icon.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange because it must work. I updated my answer with working code snippet example, just run the snippet and click on three dots and console log will be fired

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code:

```
window.showMenu = function(){
   // put your code here
}
```

Comment: Why? How should adding an empty function resolve the initial problem properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase empty function is just an example `window.showMenu = function(triggeringElement, menu){ /* your code here */}`

Comment: finally, someone who understand

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it